# Approaching serialization without common base class

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-geometry

I am looking for some design advices for the following problem:

I am using boost geometry, I have a couple of custom geometry types compatible with boost geometry (via traits), but most of the types I am using are typedefs.

```
class MyPoint
{
  // custom stuff
};
// declare traits for MyPoint for use wih boost geometry here

class MyTaggedPoint : public MyPoint
{
  // more custom stuff
};
// declare traits for MyTaggedPoint for use wih boost geometry here

// example typedefs
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<MyPoint>        Polygon;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<MyTaggedPoint>  TaggedPolygon;
```

My problem is when I want to serialize/deserialize my geometries.

Let's say all geometries are stored in a binary field in a database. If I would have a base geometry class, I would probably just write g->type() (4 bytes) and call g->save(some_outputstream) and write all of that to the binary field. Then when reading the binary field I would simply read the bytes and cast to appropriate geometry type.

But Boost geometries do **not** have a common base class.

**How do you guys usually approach serialization when there are multiple types that can be stored as binary *and you do not have a shared base class* ?**

I was thinking of maybe having a Serializer class, that returns a boost.Any and then the geometry can be casted afterward with the type that would be stored in the (de)serializer? But then the serializer would need a save method for each geometry types ? ex: Save(myPolygon), Save(myPoint)

Any ideas/experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boost's serialization](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) supports non-invasive serialization if you do not wish to reimplement the wheel.  You may even be able to find library support for their geometry types somewhere.  The interface is somewhat complicated due to XML concerns unfortunately.

Comment: +1 for Boost.Serialization, especially since he's already using Boost.

Answer (score 0):

To serialize objects to and from bytes, you ultimately need 2 functions for EACH type you have to support (primatives, objects, etc.). These are "Load()" and "Store()".

Ideally, you use a fixed interface for the bytes- a iostream, char*, some buffer object- etc.
For the sake of readability let's call it "ByteBuffer", since logically that's what its role is.

We now have something like template functions for the Serializable concept:

```
template<typename T>
ByteBuffer Store(const T& object) { // BUT, What goes here...? }

template<typename T>
T Load(const ByteBuffer& bytes);
```

Okay, this isn't going to work for anything other than the primitive types- even if we made these "visitors" or something they literally have to know every detail about the object's internals to do their job. Furthermore, "Load()" is logically a constructor (really, a FACTORY since it could easily fail). We've got to associate these with the actual objects.

To make Serializable a base class, we need to use the "curiously recurring template" pattern. To do this, we require all derived classes to have a constructor of the form:

```
T(const ByteBuffer& bytes);
```

To check for errors, we can provide a protected flag "valid" in the base class that derived constructors can set. Note that your object has to support factory-style construction anyway for Load() to work well with it.

Now we can do this right, providing "Load" as a factory:

```
template<typename T>
class Serializable // If you do reference-counting on files & such, you can add it here
{
protected:
    bool valid;

    // Require derived to mark as valid upon load
    Serializable() : valid(false) {}
    virtual ~Serializable() { valid = false; }

public:
    static T Load(const ByteBuffer& bytes); // calls a "T(bytes)" constructor

    // Store API
    virtual ByteBuffer Store() = 0;  // Interface details are up to you.
};
```

Now, just derive from the base class like so and you can pick up everything you need:

```
class MyObject : public Serializable<MyObject>
{
protected:
   // .. some members ...

   MyObject(const ByteBuffer& bytes)
   {
      //... Actual load logic for this object type ...
      // On success only:
      valid = true;
   }

public:
   virtual ByteBuffer Store() {
      //... store logic 
   }
};
```

What's cool is that you can call "MyObject::Load()" and it'll do exactly what you expect. Futhermore, "Load" can be made into the ONLY way to build the object, allowing you clean APIs for read-only files and such.

Extending this to full File APIs takes a little more work, namely adding a "Load()" that can read from a larger buffer (holding other things) and "Store()" that appends to an existing buffer.

As a side note, do NOT use boost's APIs for this. In a good design serializable objects should map 1-to-1 to packed structures of primitive types on disk- that's the only way the resulting files are really going to be usable by other programs or on other machines. Boost gives you a horrible API that mostly enables you to do things you'll regret later.